# API behind Azure AD Application Proxy: login works but requests with token return ms login site html

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, reverse-proxy, azure-ad-msal, azure-app-configuration

I have a token acquired whith MSAL and when a call the API whith the token I always have ms login site html response.

With postman (bearer token) and I still have the ms login page.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I share with you the solution that I found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `scope` is **ALL LOWER CASED**, eg:
`https://xyz.msappproxy.net/user_impersonation`

I've spent countless hours troubleshooting this issue...

Kudos to this answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187666/ms-app-proxy-works-in-browser-fails-in-app-with-to